Pandas dataframe - combine cell values as strings
I have a dataframe:
Email                | Col1      | Col2 | Col3      | Name
--------------------------------------------------------------------
john.cena@gmail.com  | CellStr11 | 1.4  | CellStr13 | John Cena
damian.doe@gmail.com | CellStr11 | 1.2  | CellStr13 | Matt Smith
john.smith@gmail.com | CellStr21 | 1.2  | CellStr23 | John Cena

I need to aggregate the values of cells of Col1, Col2 and Col3 by Name.
If row[Name] == row[Name] then:
Email                | Col1                  | Col2      | Col3                  | Name
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
john.cena@gmail.com  | CellStr11 / CellStr21 | 1.4 / 1.2 | CellStr13 / CellStr23 | John Cena
damian.doe@gmail.com | CellStr11             | 1.2       | CellStr13             | Matt Smith

I don't have to care about any other columns, their data can be lost. First I though to about this apporach:

Split the dataframe in such a way that I get the other Name matching row (learnt how to do that here
Append the columns to the end of the original dataframe

The issue here was that not all rows had the corresponding row with matching Name, which would result in some rows having the additional columns, some not (correct me if I'm wrong, if this apporach is ok that would also be fine, even better).
Is there a simple way to do it with df.apply and lambda function? Or any other more complex way? I could use:
g2[['B', 'C']].apply(lambda x: x / x.sum()) but instead of summing just join as strings, but how can I differentiate between x.B and x.C?

Have you not learned how to use groupby? In that case, start with a Pandas tutorial; Stack Overflow isn't really built to teach the basics. For example, here's the section in Ten Minutes to Pandas (which links to the User Guide: Group by: split-apply-combine).

@wjandrea I don't understand why comment this way. Stack is built for asking and answering questions. I'm still learning and got into this particular hard spot for me and by trying different things I did not come to a solution that would work so I'm asking more experienced people. If I'm asking such a question it's quite easy to deduce I don't fully understand gorupby (even with documentation) and I believe there is someone who can explain it to me so I will get it.

Oh ok, if you just didn't realize groupby was the right tool for the job, fair enough. With experience, sometimes it's hard to tell what's obvious for beginners and what's not, sorry.

No problem! Yeah and for begginer it's hard to know if you are asking the right questions and not something obvious.

If your dataframe is df:
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].astype('str')  # all the columns must be strings
gp_col = df.groupby(["Name"])[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']] \
           .agg(lambda x: " / ".join(x)) \
           .reset_index()

display(gp_col) gives:


works like a charm, thanks!

You can try DataFrame#groupby, API reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html
let's asy a DataFrame df:
   Animal  MaxSpeed
0  Falcon     380.0
1  Falcon     370.0
2  Parrot      24.0
3  Parrot      26.0

calling df.groupby('Animal') will gives you a <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at XXXXXXXXXX>, which is iterable:
for key, frame in df.groupby("Animal"):
    pass # do something here

the key is the common Animal attribute of this group, and the frame contains all DataFrames in this group, for example if we print(key, '\n', frame):
Falcon 
    Animal  Max Speed
0  Falcon      380.0
1  Falcon      370.0
Parrot 
    Animal  Max Speed
2  Parrot       24.0
3  Parrot       26.0


Thanks. I don't think I follow though. I know how to get rows by thhe reoccurring values. I need to aggregate the values for some columns. Similarly if I would sum the values for Numbers just operating on strings.

The return object of groupby provides some helper functions for aggregating grouped values, for example df.groupby("Animal").count() will return a DataFrame with two columns: the key for grouping and the count of DataFrame in grouped frames. And if you want to sum values in an column, you can try something like this: df.groupby("Animal")['Max Speed'].sum(), which will sum "Max Speed" in each group and return a new DataFrame with two columns(key and sum)
